# multiple network interface and networks

Tags: networking

I am trying to set up two different networks on two different interfaces and I'm only able to access only one of them.
the system is VM with ubuntu 18.04
The first interface ens160 should be connected to the internal network with static IP 192.168.10.XX
second interface ens192 should be connected to the internet with DHCP server dynamic IP 172.25.xx.xx

basically, I'm just setting up the static IP using the UI and set the default gateway to be the same as the static IP.

Just to be clear when each one of the network interfaces is disabled the other network is working properly.

The result is that only one network is working at the time.

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Good, I've converted my comment into an answer so you can mark it as accepted and therefore mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one should have a gateway set. Set your static without a Gateway address. You should then be able to access the internal 192.168.0.0/24 network without issue.